# RefineryCMS Reusing partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

What I am trying to do is use the refinery/admin/images/insert template to insert images in my own engine..  I am a complete noob at rails and refinerycms... Any help regarding this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Refinery engine, you can generate image insertion support by specifying the field as an image when you generate it:

```
rails generate refinery:engine title:string image:image
```

Refinery understands that, when you say something is an image, it should convert this to a link to the image insertion functionality for you.

Don't worry if you have an existing extension, you can just generate a new one and copy what gets generated for the image support into your one.